# PHP Encryption Method Comparison

Tags: php, encryption, yii, cryptography, yii2

I was recently asked to create a method for encryption / decryption of a URL string.  I quickly produced a 1 liner and shot it out.

I was then provided with the code from another developer and asked my opinion.  I looked at his to find a much more complex function.

**My questions:**

> What are the specific differences here?
>
> Are there shortfalls found in the short solution?

We are encrypting a json encoded array and passing it via query string URL.

**Long solution:**

```
public function Encrypt($message, $key = 'defaultkey') {

    //Create an instance of the mcrypt resource
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');

    //Create a random intialization vector and initialize
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);

    // Create a Timestamp and add it.
    $T = new \DateTime('NOW');
    $message = $T->format("YmdHis") . $message;

    // PKCS7 Padding
    //get the block size of the cipher
    $b = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');

    //What is the purpose?
    $dataPad = $b-(strlen($message)%$b);
    $message .= str_repeat(chr($dataPad), $dataPad);

    //convert to hexidec string
    $encrypted_data = bin2hex(mcrypt_generic($td, $message));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    return $encrypted_data;
}
```

**Short Solution:**

```
public function Encrypt($message, $key = 'defaultkey') {
    
    $T = new \DateTime('NOW');
    return bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $T->format("YmdHis").$message, 'ecb'));
}
```

Comment: i think this is more proper address for your question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's a good point.  Thank you.

Comment: you can use upvote for comment if you've found useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real difference is the padding. Triple DES is a symmetric block cipher and such only operates on a single full block (8 byte). A mode of operation like ECB enables it to encrypt many full blocks. When your data is not a multiple of the block size, it has to be padded for it to be encrypted.

MCrypt uses zero padding by default. It will fill up the plaintext with 0x00 bytes until a multiple of the block size is reached. Those additional padding bytes have to be removed during decryption (usually done with `rtrim()`). This means that if the plaintext ends with 0x00 bytes, those will also be removed which might break your plaintext.

PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding on the other hand pads with a byte that represents the number of padding bytes. If the plaintext is already a multiple of the block size, it will add a full block of padding. Doing it this way enables it to only remove the padding and not additional plaintext bytes during decryption.

Whether `mcrypt_generic_init()` or `mcrypt_encrypt()` was used doesn't really make a difference.

---

**You should never use ECB mode.** It is not semantically secure. It means that the same plaintext block will always result in the same ciphertext block. Since you're encrypting URLs the first couple of blocks will stay the same for similar URLs after observing many ciphertexts. An attacker might get additional information out of this.

Use at least CBC mode with a random IV. The IV doesn't need to be hidden, so it can be easily prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off during decryption.

It is also best to have the ciphertext authenticated to detect manipulation. You can use a message authentication code such as HMAC-SHA256 with a different key. A better way would be to simply use an authenticated mode such as GCM or EAX.

Comment: Given that the string will never end in spaces or zeros, and assuming I understand the implication of 0x00 bytes, it sounds like i'm safe.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Then you're safe on that front. See my updated answer about other security implications.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information related to security.  I'm being purposely dismissive about the strength of the encryption.  The data could technically be sent in plain text with zero risk.